# Found Bundled Python and EXCEPTIONAL_ACCESS_VIOLATION error

Tags: python, error

I just installed Blender today, and it was installed succesfully. After that, I tried to open the app. The program opened with no problem, but whenever I click new project, or I tried to use any feature Blender has, the program crashed. After that I tried to look up the solution in this forum. Someone said I should try to use the command prompt to debug the app, then i open the directory of blender exe file and start it with `blender --debug` command. Then, i got some error messages.

[image: error1]

So, based on the suggestions i got after reading some questions in the forum, I opened the preference and changed the frequency to 44100 Hz and the bit to 24 signed bit. After that, I tried to restart Blender. But, I still have the same problem as before, the program will crash whenever I start a new project or try to use any feature. I tried to lookup the problem from command prompt, and i got these error informations.

[image: error2]

I think the problem lies in
(1)version 280 sub 39 date unknown has unknown
(2) found bundled python: directory line
(3) Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

But i don't understand any of those. Could anyone help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: This seems like an issue with your graphics driver or unsupported hardware. Please check if your system fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for Blender 2.8x. If it does, then update your graphics driver.

Comment: I've checked my hardware and it seems it is compatible with Blender, at least for the minimum requirement. Here i list my computer specifications.

OS: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit, (6.1, Build 7601)
Model: HP EliteBook 8470p
Processor: Intel Core i5-3360M CPU @2.80GHz (4 CPUs)
Memory: 8 GB

Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 with 1696 MB memory

Comment: Oh, I also have tried to download the zip version, and started it both after extracting it and before extracting it. both of them didn't work, with the exactly same problem

Comment: Try to update your graphics driver from the [Intel website](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28799/Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-33-?product=64895). Officially your integrated GPU isn't supported, although there are some workarounds implemented and Germano Cavalcante tries to make it work.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot, now I can use blender!